# Python creating username and password program

Tags: python

I am just a beginner programmer as of right now, and I am trying to create a username/password program. Here is my code below:

```
username = 'Polly1220'

password = 'Bob'

userInput = input("What is your username?\n")

if userInput == username:
    a=input("Password?\n")   
    if a == password:
        print("Welcome!")
    else:
        print("That is the wrong password.")
else:
    print("That is the wrong username.")
```

Whenever I run my program and input the correct password as shown, it always says that the password is incorrect.

Comment: Are you missing a colon after the first if statement?

Comment: You never assign the password input to anything

Comment: You need to set `userInput = input("Password?\n")` (damn @Eugene you beat me to it)

Comment: Ah I see I forgot about that. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PollytheProgrammer Also, take a look at [`getpass.getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass).

Comment: Try printing `userInput` to make sure it's what you think it is

Answer (score 9):

You need to assign the second input statement to userInput:

```
if userInput == username:
    userInput = input("Password?\n")   
    if userInput == password:
       print("Welcome!")
    else:
       print("That is the wrong password.")
else:
    print("That is the wrong username.")
```

Comment: I did. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting this response as answered so other users know it has an answer. Thank you.

Comment: You were really fast on this one! plus one for that pal :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign the variable:

```
if userInput == username
   userInput = input("Password?\n")   
    if userInput == password:
        print("Welcome!")
    else:
        print("That is the wrong password.")
else:
    print("That is the wrong username.")
```